# Websocket server on cloud to store data

Tags: websocket, cloud

Firstly let me tell you i am novice to cloud computing .

My objective is to read sensor data continuously from a device , store it in cloud servers and then retrieve the data to a website real time.

As per my research i found out that this can be done by using mbed boards with ethernet.

I will read the data from the sensors and pass it to the websocket server continuously in JSON format and from there using java script i will display that data on my website.

Issue here is i don't know how to store this data on cloud. Should this websocket server be on some cloud and also how this server will be able to store the data.

Plz help. Or is there any other way to achieve this??

Sorry if this question doesn't make any sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run your websocket applications through Cloud , then there are plenty of ways.
I am actually not sure that is what you are expecting or not but I have used jelastic to do the same and it worked quite well and its very easy. Try once to implement your application over Jelastic .

Following link 
http://blog.jelastic.com/2013/07/10/websockets-tutorial-tomee/
might help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about the cloud, is not clear if you plan to use an IaaS or a PaaS provider. On an IaaS you will need to set-up everything, meaning install the stack, the database and to configure websockets, when in a PaaS you have everything as a service and you just need to enable these services and to use them without configuring anything.

If you are looking for a WebSocket implementation example, you should take a look to this [one](https://github.com/fbelzunc/tomcat7-websocket-clickstart) which will automatically set-up a WebSocket application on the cloud. Maybe from here, you could start designing your app in the case you want to use a Java web application.

To store your data on the cloud, as far as I know, you can use SQL and NoSQL technologies, which means that you can use MySQL, Mongo or PostgreSQL databases. However, for a realtime application, I am not sure about what is the best choice.